# JQGrid php 4.4.0 adding custom rows and table in view model

Tags: php, json, jqgrid, viewmodel, subgrid

I have been working on this for past three days but I still can't make this to do.
I need to add more rows or more details in view model than what I'm showing on the table. and the view model does have a subgrid too. I'm trying hard but I cant get it work.  The data are extracted from mysql database.

Any help is much appreciated.

the datatype I'm using is JSON...

I completed a part where I can show subgrid within the grid but not in model view...

this is what I have done so far
https://www.dropbox.com/s/658tu0nndzcve4h/subgrid.png?dl=0

But I want to view subgrid in view model as on this link
https://www.dropbox.com/s/bofu0911gmbxxps/60sMb.png?dl=0

How to achieve it?

this code displays subgrid within table.

```
$grid->setSubGridGrid("subgrid.php");
```

how to bring display this in view model?

I tried this

```
$grid->setSubGridGrid("view"=>"subgrid.php");
```

but no luck.

Comment: You should post what you tried so far and be more specific about any problems you encountered...

Comment: The text of your question provide a few information only. You should divide the problems in clear formulated questions with clear description, code fragments and so on. You wrote "add more rows". It's too unclear. An example would be fine. Have the information the same properties (should it be displayed in the same columns)? Where you want to show the information? (above the data rows, below the data rows?). Do you tried to use `footerrow: true` option for example? Which `datatype` you use? ...

Comment: You should add what you have tried.